# Problem in inserting new key pairs in Dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
s = "eat"
for i in s:
    d = dict()
    d[i] = i
    if i in d:
        continue
    else:
        d[i] = 1
```

I have tried several times but it is only appending `{'t': 't'}` as output,
I'm expecting `{'e': 'e', 'a': 'a', 't', 't'}` as the output

Comment: You're redifining `d` every iteration. Move it outside of the loop. Also, the first `if` statement always gets triggered and the entire thing is unnecessary.

Comment: `d = dict()` creates a new dict in each iteration

Comment: Please do some basic debugging before posting, e.g. using https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit or even just `print`ing things - the problem would become obvious quite quickly.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [ask] for tips for future questions.

Comment: FWIW, you could use a dict comprehension if you'd prefer: `d = {i: i for i in s}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To solve the problem: see the linked duplicate - treating the `s` string as both the key list and the values list. To answer the debugging question - that is effectively a typo, and we generally close such questions because they cannot be helpful to others. My hint is to think carefully about the logic: what happens when the code `d = dict()` runs? In particular, what will happen to any dictionary that was already stored in `d`? Therefore, how many times should this code happen? Therefore, should it be inside the loop, or outside?

Comment: as wjandrea said you can just use [dict comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) like `d = {i: i for i in s}`; but also, you should know that `else` if unnecessary after [`if...continue`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue/#working), and that you can use [`not in`](https://realpython.com/python-in-operator/) instead of *`if _ in __...else`*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are creating a new dictionary with each iteration of the loop. As a result, you are getting `{'t': 't'}` As angwrk stated in his response, you want to declare the dictionary outside of your for loop.